# How to connect Spring MVC application and cloud storage

Tags: spring, web-applications, cloud

I do application on Spring MVC where I need to store users photos. There are some ways to store files, but they have disadvantages:

1. in local storage - limit of host storage
2. in DB - cashe, limit of DB, long process of converting images to store in DB

I want ask you, is there some way to upload images(any files) on cloud service, for example https://i.onthe.io/ or [google drive](https://www.google.com/intl/ru_uA/drive/) and then load them to my application (on JSP page).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There will be **2 steps** to upload into Google Drive from a Spring application.

1.Implement **Oauth2 Authorization** - Either by using [Google APIs](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/google-api-java-client/oauth2) or [Spring OAuth2](https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-boot-oauth2/)

2.Use [Drive API Client Library for Java](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/apis/drive/v3) to upload/download files into Google drive.

Refer GoogleDrive API JavaDoc [here](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/drive/v3/java/latest/).

Comment: I understood: the best way to store images is database. To store it in cloud I need to write more code than I have already in all my application(

Comment: Please make sure What you want before ask someone else.

Answer (score 0):

Spring Cloud AWS maybe can help you [enter link description here](http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-aws/spring-cloud-aws.html#_using_amazon_web_services)

Comment: Yeah, I saw it, but it looks some unclear and difficult. There are no examples of dirrect connect and save files. I want find some ways to connect to free popular storages: google, yandex, i.onthe, etc.

Comment: Google disk provide free 10GB for free.